# FaceBook post on user wall not working in IE

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, azure

I am trying to post on user's wall in an facebook app, this is not working in Internet Explorer, in other browser it is working.
this Error is shown:
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
in IE and other browser token is different.

```
     try{
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $attachment = array('access_token '=>$access_token ,
    'message' => $pageUrl,'name' =>"Test Name",
'link' => $pageUrl,'description'=>$desc,'picture'=>$img,'caption'=>'test '                                                              );
                $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);                                                                    }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e){ 
         echo $e;
        }
```

Comment: No need of access token here
 try{
               
                $attachment = array(
        'message' => $pageUrl,'name' =>"Test Name",
    'link' => $pageUrl,'description'=>$desc,'picture'=>$img,'caption'=>'test '                     );
                    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);                 }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e){ 
             echo $e;
            }

Comment: Some Time post  successfully on user wall in IE and some time not posting.

Answer (score 0):

its php code not js, browser doesn't matter,
Check user is logged in or not or you're getting access token or not

```
var_dump($access_token);
```

Comment: string(48) "333759810014488|a4530ca0ce096275af8ffedfee65a40e" OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: So your access token is obviously expired … get a new one. If that doesn’t work with IE only, than you’re probably having the old third-party-cookie problem. Search for that and P3P policy header.

Answer (score 0):

For helping other guys in here, I am answering your question.

Since it's an IE issue, you probably need to add a p3p header to your responses so it allows 3rd party cookies.

See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx

or for php specific coding

http://www.sitepoint.com/p3p-cookies-ie6/